# signature get error on Alljoyn framework?

Tags: alljoyn

i'm working Android App use Alljoyn framework and i have some prolem

i have a custom object

```
public class Package implements BusObject {


    public static enum DataSendType {
        TEXT,IMAGE
    }

    public static enum PackageStatus {
        NONE, SENDING, DONE
    }

    @Signature("s")
    private String m_id;
    @Signature("a")
    private ArrayList<DataPackage> m_listPackage;
    @Signature("r")
    private PackageStatus m_status;
    @Signature("r")
    private DataSendType m_type;
    @Signature("s")
    private String m_packageName;
}
```

and interface

```
@BusInterface (name="xxxx.simpleinterface")
public interface SimpleInterface {

    @BusSignal (name="Chat", signature="o")
    public void Chat(Package message) throws BusException;
}
```

but i get this error **cannot marshal class Package into 'o'** when use Chat(Package)..

pls help me, because i can't get this error out for 2 weeks.

sorry because my English is too bad :)

Comment: What are you trying to send as part of the signal is it a struct with an id string, array of bytes, enum status, enum sendtype, string?  most importantly what is the m_listPackage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at your code it looks like what you are trying to send is a struct the signature for a struct should be `"r"` or the actual signature surrounded by parenthesizes `(` and `)`. i.e. for `Package` the signature would be `"(sayiis)"`

- With AllJoyn you can send an array but not an `ArrayList` and you must specify the type of data that is in the array.
- Since your `DataSendType` specified `TEXT` or `IMAGE` I made the assumption that you want to send an array of bytes.
- Most of the items I did not add a signature to because AllJoyn can figure out the signature using reflection.  AllJoyn however does not know that enums will be transmitted as integers so I did have to specify the signature for the enums.
- Package did not have to implement BusObject.  In your code when you implement your `SimpleInterface` that should extend the `SimpleInterface` and `BusObject'
- Anything sent using AllJoyn should be public so the interface can read the member variables.

  ```
  public class Package {
      public static enum DataSendType{
          TEXT,
          IMAGE
      }

      public static enum PackageStatus {
          NONE,
          SENDING,
          DONE
      }

      @Position(0)
      public String m_id;
      @Position(1)
      public byte[] m_listPackage;
      @Position(2)
      @Signature("i")
      public PackageStatus m_status;
      @Position(3)
      @Signature("i")
      public DataSendType m_type;
      @Position(4)
      public String m_packageName;
  }
  ```

for the interface the signature should be `"r"` for struct the signature `"o"` means object path.  This is an AllJoyn object path which means it just a string with path data.

```
@BusInterface (name="xxxx.simpleinterface")
public interface SimpleInterface {

    @BusSignal (name="Chat", signature="r")
    public void Chat(Package message) throws BusException;
}
```

If you really need to use an ArrayList convert the ArrayList to an actual array before sending the `Chat` signal.