# AllJoyn BusSignalReply error

Tags: java, android, multiplayer, alljoyn, local-network

I'm building an Android App that uses the AllJoyn Framework. Basically, I need a lan communication in order to create lobbies and allow people that are joined to them, play a certain game.

For this, I have created an object Lobby and its corresponding LobbyInterface. What I have done for now is:
-An user can create a Lobby and this is shown in a list in all connected devices.
-An user can select a created Lobby and join it.

What I want now is for a list to be refreshed when a user joins the lobby. For this, I need to get the user list that is in the lobby. I'm trying to get this list from the LobbyInterface. I know that  I can't get complex objects (if they are not built structure-wise) through the bus, but I'm trying to get a simple array of Strings.

This is my code:

```
LobbyClass:

    public class Lobby implements LobbyInterface, BusObject {
    private String[] lstUsers;
    private String name;

    public Lobby(String name){
        this.name = name;
        lstUsers = new String[4];
    }

    /**
    extra code here
    **/

    @Override
    public String[] getLstUsers() throws BusException {
        return lstUsers;
    }

}
```

LobbyInterface Class:

```
@BusInterface(name = "com.example.cantor.pruebamultiplayerv3.lobby", announced = "true")
public interface LobbyInterface {


    @BusMethod(replySignature = "as")
    String[] getLstUsers() throws BusException;
}
```

This is the method from which I'm calling this, form an UsersFacade Class:

```
public String[] getLstUsers(){
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "USER could get users list");
                return lobbyI.getLstUsers();
            } catch (BusException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "USER error getting users lst");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }
```

This always returns null, and the error is:

```
04-23 21:09:47.327 5864-5864/com.example.cantor.pruebamultiplayerv3 W/System.err: org.alljoyn.bus.ErrorReplyBusException: org.alljoyn.Bus.ErStatus
04-23 21:09:47.346 5864-5864/com.example.cantor.pruebamultiplayerv3 W/System.err:     at org.alljoyn.bus.ProxyBusObject.methodCall(Native Method)
04-23 21:09:47.346 5864-5864/com.example.cantor.pruebamultiplayerv3 W/System.err:     at org.alljoyn.bus.ProxyBusObject.access$300(ProxyBusObject.java:35)
04-23 21:09:47.346 5864-5864/com.example.cantor.pruebamultiplayerv3 W/System.err:     at org.alljoyn.bus.ProxyBusObject$Handler.invoke(ProxyBusObject.java:264)
04-23 21:09:47.346 5864-5864/com.example.cantor.pruebamultiplayerv3 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
04-23 21:09:47.346 5864-5864/com.example.cantor.pruebamultiplayerv3 W/System.err:     at $Proxy2.getLstUsers(Unknown Source)
04-23 21:09:47.346 5864-5864/com.example.cantor.pruebamultiplayerv3 W/System.err:     at com.example.cantor.pruebamultiplayerv3.UsersFacade.getLstUsers(UsersFacade.java:70)
```

I know that I can return structures specifying position and type. But I've seen that I can work with simple array of Strings:
https://allseenalliance.org/docs/api/java/org/alljoyn/bus/annotation/Signature.html

I've been reading other answers here, but these are for complex data, like this one:
[signature get error on Alljoyn framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397088/signature-get-error-on-alljoyn-framework)

What is wrong with my code? Any alternatives?

Thank you very much for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I just found the error. I was working with an empty list (some of the slots had a null, since I was trying to fill the list). I filled it with empty strings and now it works...

```
public Lobby(String name){
        this.name = name;
        lstUsers = new String[4];
        for (int i = 0; i <=3; i++){
            lstUsers[i] = "";
        }
    }
```